# Iframes resizing to dynamic content

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to make my iframe resize itself to the content i put inside it. My problem is that it works as long as the content is longer but as soon as the content is shorter it does not become smaller. I have tried multiple solutions which don't work.

Is it possible to refresh only the iframe component and not the whole page every x milliseconds? That might solve my problem.

Edit 3*

```
<head>
<script>
function resizeIframe(objIframe) {
  objIframe = document.getElementById('myiframe');    
  objIframe.style.height = 'auto';
  objIframe.style.height = obj.contentDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<iframe align="right" src="./home.php" name="myiframe" width="100%" 
height="100" id="myiframe" marginwidth="0" margin="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" 
onload="resizeIframe(this)"/></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Edited above. Sorry i am a newbie at this. I was trying to read previous related posts but none of them seem to work

Comment: The problem is that the `html` element (what documentElement refers to) has the same height as the viewport. So if you made your iframe have 500px height once already, reading back the offsetHeight of documentElement will always return you a value of 500, even if the actual content has shrunk to less by now. Try with the height of the body element instead.

Comment: objIframe.body.scrollHeight + 'px' didnt work